# Storing in a JSON file vs. JSON object vs. MYSQL database

Tags: json, node.js

I've programmed a chat application using nodejs, expressjs and socket.io.
So, When I used MYSQL database the application slows down then I replaced it with storing the data using JSON objects (in the server-side of nodejs).

Now everything is ok and the application is working well, but If I want to release an update of the nodejs' `app.js` file it should be restarted, so, everything in the JSON objects will be deleted!

How can I fix this problem? and can I store in a JSON file to fix it? and will the application stay at the same speed or what?

Comment: @yashpandey Yes, that's right, my application is a runtime chat, I don't want to use MYSQL because it will be the same (slow), My answer is about the speed of JSON object storing speed and JSON file storing speed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Storing data in RAM will be always faster than writing to a database, but the problem in your case you need to persist it somewhere.

There are many solutions to this problem but if you are using JSON's, I recommend to look at [`mongodb`](https://docs.mongodb.com/) database.

MongoDb supports multiple storage engines, but the one that you are interested is `in memory`.

An interesting architecture for you can be the following [replica set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/) configuration:

1. Primary with `in-memory` storage engine
2. Secondary with `in-memory` storage engine
3. An other Secondary with `wiredtiger` storage engine.

You will have the benefits of speed by storing in RAM, and also it will be persisted in the database.

A simpler possibility will be to use a key-store db like [`redis`](https://redis.io/). Easier to configure.

Comment: I think that your answer as very useful and will solve the problem. But `Mongodb` is so hard to install and learn and I have wrote many lines of codes and it's so hard to change. Is there another way can help me please ?

Comment: you dont have to install mongo I suppose. you can use it on cloud - https://mlab.com/. You can use that , they give 500 mb free and there is no hard learning curve in mongo